# When using GeoWebCacche, vector layer cannot display completely

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, vector-tiles, geowebcache, wmts

Using GeoServer 2.19.0, I'm generating vector-tiles (formats:mapbox-vector-tile, SRS:EPSG:4326,
Gridset:EPSG:4326) for the full extent of a layer. After Seed, I open a result page from web console, but the tile cannot display completely. At some zoom, some polygon cannot display, some are only partially displayed. After some time, it can display correctly. How can I solve this problem?

environment：

GeoServer version:2.19.0

OpenLayers version:4.6.5

Other setting are automatically generated

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the problem a whole missing tile or just part of a polygon?

Comment: I think is missing tile.I try to reseed layer and refresh page,but it does't work

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply，then I will submit the question